# SQL request or php solution to manage employers

Tags: php, sql, symfony

My entity :

```
class User{
    id   : int 
    name : string
    boss : User()
}
```

I want to create a function that return an array() of users that work under a giving user. 
example :

```
public function MyEmployers( User $user , array $usersList  )
{
    $myEmployers = array();

   ...

    return $myEmployers;
}

$results =  $this->myEmployers ( $employer1 , $allEmployers)
dump ( $results );

$results  = [ 4 , 5 , 6 ];
```

[image]

I found a solution if someone can improve it feel free :

public $tree = array();

```
public function MyEmployers(User $user)
{

    $superior_key_id = array();
    $all_users = $this->getallusers();
    $id = $user->getId();

    foreach ($all_users as $user) {
        if ($user->getSuperior())
            $superior_key_id[$user->getSuperior()->getId()][] = $user;
    }
    $this->getSubEmployee($this->getUser(), $superior_key_id);

    return ($this->tree);

}

public function getSubEmployee($user, $superior_key_id)
{
    if (isset($superior_key_id[$user->getId()])) {
        foreach ($superior_key_id[$user->getId()] as $user) {
            $this->tree[] = $user;
            $this->getSubEmployee($user, $superior_key_id);
        }
    }
    return $user;
}
```

this one will get all bosses if you're interested :

```
public function MyBosses(User $user)
{
    $bosses = array();

    while ($user->getSuperior()) {

        array_push($bosses, $user->getSuperior());

        $user = $user->getSuperior();
    }

    return $bosses;

}
```

Comment: So, if I ask for who work under `boss`, I would return `employer1` to `empoyer6`? Or just `employer1` and `employer2`?

Comment: everyone work under boss 
the result will be something like this 
$results  = [1 , 2  , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 ];

Answer (score -1):

You could set up a one-to-many relationship between `boss` and `employee`

So you're user class could look like:

```
class User{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id()
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    private $name;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="employee")
    */
    private $boss;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="boss")
    */
    private $employees;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->employees = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * @return Collection|employees[]
    */
    public function getEmployees(): Collection
    {
        return $this->employees;
    }

    public function addEmployee(employee $employee): self
    {
        if (!$this->employees->contains($employee)) {
            $this->employees[] = $employee;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEmployee(employee $employee): self
    {
        if ($this->employees->contains($employee)) {
            $this->employees->removeElement($employee);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBoss(): ?Usesr
    {
        return $this->boss;
    }

    public function setBoss(?User $boss): self
    {
        $this->boss = $boss;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

You would need to set up the database relationship with the [symfony make:entity command](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#the-manytoone-onetomany-association).

To get all employeers under a user, you could do something like:

```
function getAllEmployeesUnder(User $user)
{
    $allEmployees = [];

    foreach ($user->getEmployees as $employee) {
        $allEmployees[] = $employee;
        $allEmployees = array_merge($allEmployees, $this->getAllEmployeesUnder($employee));
    }

    return $allEmployees;
}
```

Comment: I found a solution and i want to share it maybe it will help a fellow developer one day